# NO WIFI ADAPTER, Ubuntu 19.10, Lenovo S340, Intel Device 02f0

Tags: iwlwifi

Lenovo S340, Ubuntu 19.10.

I can't properly identify the Network Card. lspci outputs Intel Corporation Device 02f0.

I've tried Ubuntu 18.04 before with no luck.

I cannot believe this does not work out of the box. I've tried several drivers, all to no avail.

While installing, I was able to connect to my wifi and download the packages.

After installed, ubuntu no longer finds a Wifi Adapter.

iwconfig ouput is plainly: lo      no wireless extensions

I don't know what to do anymore. I can't plug an Ethernet Cable in because there no Ethernet port, so... what can I do???

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `uname -r`